# Apple MacOS Mojave Profil Manager postgres_real writing huge amount of data

Tags: database, macos, server

having a problem since updating macos to mojave and apple server to 5.7.1.

The postgres_real process writing a huge amount of data (per day 1 TB) and slowing down the server until profil manager is unreachable.

After a restart everything is looking good, after time (dont know extactly) postgres_real beginning the write of death.

I had reindex the database but this doesnt fix the problem.

Maybe you can help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it out finally.

The Profil Manager is keeping all activ tasks of a group until the task has completely finished. If one of the iPads not refreshing or pushing correctly the task keeps open.
New tasks of the same group are additional, so the activ task getting huge over time (group with 10000>tasks).

So I have to cancel activ tasks with huge amount of data.

Case can be closed :-)